# How can I avoid error "sObject type 'StaticResource' is not supported." in the Post Install script?

Tags: managed-package, exception, static-resources, isv, postinstall

I am sampling data inside the Package Post Install script from a Static Resource, but script fails with an error:

```
Error Message: common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: sObject type 'StaticResource' is not supported.
```

The listing of classes are shown below:

```
public inherited sharing class InstallHandler implements System.InstallHandler {
    public void onInstall(InstallContext context) {
        Setup.default();
    } 
}
```

The Setup class:

```
public inherited sharing class Setup{
   private static List<SObject> load(String staticResourceName) {
       List<StaticResource> srs = [ SELECT Id, Name, Body FROM StaticResource WHERE Name = :staticResourceName ];
       Object data = JSON.deserialize(srs[0].Body.toString());
       ....
   }
   public static void default() {
       load('jsonDataDump');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is enough to set `without sharing` access inside the class which queries the `StaticResource`.

```
public without sharing class Setup{
   private static List<SObject> load(String staticResourceName) {
       List<StaticResource> srs = [ SELECT Name, Body FROM StaticResource WHERE Name = :staticResourceName ];
       Object data = JSON.deserialize(srs[0].Body.toString());
       ....
   }
   public static void default() {
       load('jsonDataDump');
   }
}
```

Actuall it is even possible to create an inner class to follow the security trampoline design approach like following:

```
public inherited sharing class Setup{
   public without sharing class StaticResourceProvider {
       private static List<StaticResource> load(String staticResourceName) {
           return  [ SELECT Name, Body FROM StaticResource WHERE Name = :staticResourceName ];
       }
   }
   private static List<SObject> load(String staticResourceName) {
       List<StaticResource> srs = StaticResourceProvider.load(staticResourceName);
       Object data = JSON.deserialize(srs[0].Body.toString());
       ....
   }
   public static void default() {
       load('jsonDataDump');
   }
}
```

Also, this is not necessary to include `Id` field in Apex SOQL queries, since this field is always queried and returned in results.